# How to send real time coordinates from location file to different file in python?

Tags: python, function, websocket, geolocation, python-module

Working on Application where location module gives real time coordinates, I need to use those coordinates in another module in same application to trigger events.

location module is an infinite loop, so I cannot call the function from different module. I tried sockets as well but no luck

Comment: What about a Pipe or Queue?

Comment: is it possible to send data to different modules with Pipe or Queue?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how your application is structured, but in my case I call e.g. a module which reads pictures an puts them to a pipe, so the processing module is able to read them out of the pipe and process them.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, the module mentioned in example , reads the pictures continuously and puts them in pipe? Is there any example for reference

Comment: I added an answer, do not hesitate to ask if you need further help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your main script is calling the modules you could use a pipe or a queue.

See the code examples on https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html, e.g.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```